# Cucumber command line executing multiple scenarios under single tag reference

Tags: command-line, cucumber, gherkin

I have multiple feature files each with multiple scenarios and we use @tag references all over the shop. We can run a single test from the command line by referencing a single tag reference no problem. However if there is multiple scenarios sitting under a single @tag it will only run the first scenario and not all scenarios under that tag. If we do it at the feature level tag id it will run all tests under that feature. Without going through and adding a tag to every scenario that doesn't have one how can we fix this?

```
@featuretagreference
@featuretagreference-AC1 (one scenario written)
@featuretagreference-AC2 (2 scenarios written)
@featuretagreference-AC3 (one scenario written)
Total tests (scenarios) is 4
```

In command line: execute @featuretagreference will run all tests (AC1, 2, and 3 - 4 tests run)
In command line: execute @featuretagreference-AC1 will run AC1 test - 1 test run
In command line: execute @featuretagreference-AC3 will run AC3 test - 1 test run
In command line: execute @featuretagreference-AC2 will run AC2 test - 1 test run (this should run both scenarios under this tag but it only runs the first one)

Is there fix for this or is it a limitation of the command line execution?

note: AC = Acceptance Criteria

Comment: For reference, we use eclipse on CentOS. And the reason we have this setup is that simply one acceptance criteria may require more than one test but would like to be able to test an individual acceptance criteria to ensure all tests/scenarios written pass, this is fine as long as one AC only has one scenario, seems a bit rubbish to me, surely there is a way around this

Answer (score 0):

You can run cucumber against a folder, so by organising your features in a particular hierarchy you can run a topical subset of features e.g.

```
features
  - api
  - ui
    - registration
    - inventory
```

you can run just the api tests with `cucumber features/api` and just the inventory ones with `cucumber/features/ui/inventory`

This is far simpler than tagging, which is something you should use rarely.